# 'Graph' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString' on Windows Docker

Tags: python, windows, docker, tensorflow

I'm trying to run tutorials : https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html

I got below error message:

```
root@db411995c219:~/pjh# python fully_connected_feed.py

Extracting data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 231, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 227, in main
    run_training()
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 164, in run_training
    summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, sess.graph)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/summary_io.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.add_graph(graph_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/summary_io.py", line 168, in add_graph
    graph_bytes = graph_def.SerializeToString()
**AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString'**
```

How can I resolve this?

Additional info:
I'm using the docker image with the command:

```
docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

But I got the version of TensorFlow 0.7.1.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.__version__)
0.7.1
```

What's the newest docker image name?

Comment: What is your version of TensorFlow? Try to update to 0.9

Comment: I have added more information on the question. What's the newest docker image name?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd vdocker') DO %i    
docker run -it tensorflow/tensorflow:r0.9-devel
```

And the tag list is on this site: 
https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/ 
https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/